# How to access a slice from pre-defined 'Range' in a struct?

Tags: rust, slice

Accessing a slice is straightforward using slice syntax: `slice = vector[i..j]`

In the case where the range is stored however, from what I can tell you can't do:

```
struct StructWithRange {
    range: std::ops::Range<usize>,
}

fn test_slice(s: &StructWithRange, vector: &Vec<i32>) {
    let slice = &vector[s.range];
    println!("{:?}", slice); // prints [2, 3]
}

fn main() {
    let vector = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let s = StructWithRange {
        range: 1..3
    };

    test_slice(&s, &vector);
}
```

This gives the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:6:25
  |
6 |     let slice = &vector[s.range];
  |                         ^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Is there a way to get the slice from a range without expanding it?
eg: `vector[s.range.start..s.range.end]`

If a `usize` in a struct can be used for an index lookup, why can't a `Range<usize>` be used in the same way?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] as it should work but without a clear example it's difficult to understand what's possibly wrong with code you are not showing. This MCVE should also include the error message you get from the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message occurs because `Range` does not implement `Copy` and `Index` consumes its index.

It can be solved by adding a call to `.clone()`: `&vector[s.range.clone()]`.

---

If you [check the code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops.rs.html#2037), it links to the rejected proposal to add `Copy` to `Range` in the case where its parameter is `Copy` [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/27186).

The rejection reason is:

> These don't have it because they're iterators.
>
> The choice of removing Copy impls instead of adjusted for loop desugaring or linting was made to prevent this problematic case:
>
> ```
> let mut iter = 0..n;
> for i in iter { if i > 2 { break; } }
> iter.collect()
> ```
>
> Here iter is actually not mutated, but copied. `for i in &mut iter` is required to mutate the iterator.
>
> We could switch to linting against using an iterator variable after it was copied by a for loop, but there was no decision towards that.

Answer (score 5):

Since `Index` is a trait requiring the following function:

```
fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output
```

It consumes/moves the value used for indexing (`index`). In your case you are attempting to index the slice using a `Range` from a borrowed struct, but since you are only passing a reference and the range doesn't implement `Copy`, this fails.

You can fix it by e.g. changing the definition of `test_slice` to consume `StructWithRange` or `clone()`ing the `s.range` in the index.